# Not able to pass multiple api responses from resolver to component

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to fetch responses from two different apis and merges it responses to send as a single object to the resolver.

I'm using resolver to pass the data to the Document component to load.
But, I'm not able to fetch the responses accordingly.

Can anyone knows help me out with this?

I need to pass single object as a response from the multiple api calls.

```
  resolve():Observable<any> {
    return new Observable(observer => {
      let filterValue = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('stateFilter-local'));
      if (filterValue?.selection?.length > 0) {
        delete filterValue['selection'];
        sessionStorage.removeItem('stateFilter-local');
        sessionStorage.setItem('stateFilter-local', JSON.stringify(filterValue));
      }
     this.service.getCOALatestLogBookID(false).subscribe({
        next: (response) => {
          if (response['value'][0] != undefined) {
            let maxVaule = response['value'][0].id;
            this.service.getCOALatestLogBookID(true).subscribe({
              next: (result) => {
                const spConfigValue: number = 4999; //+environment.documentsGridLimit;                
                let lobvalue = (+maxVaule / spConfigValue);
                if (!Number.isInteger(lobvalue)) {
                  lobvalue = Math.floor(lobvalue) + 1;
                }
                let array = [];
                let initailValue = +result['value'][0].id;
                let endValue = initailValue + spConfigValue;
                for (let f = 0; f < lobvalue; f++) {
                  let filter = initailValue + ',' + endValue;
                  array.push(filter);
                  initailValue = endValue + 1;
                  endValue = endValue + spConfigValue;
                }
                this.modelList1=[];
                combineLatest(array.map(number => this.service.getCOALogBookGrid(number, spConfigValue.toString()))).subscribe((res: any) => {
                  res.map(item => {
                    console.log('forkJoin - ' + this.modelList.length + ' - ' + item?.['value'].length);
                    this.modelList.push(item);
                    let dd = --array.length;
                    if (dd == 0) {
                      const response = {
                        spListMaxId: maxVaule,
                        spListMinId: result['value'][0].id,
                        model: this.modelList1
                      }
                      this.modelList1=[...this.modelList];
                      observer.next(response);
                      observer.complete();
                    }
                  });
                });                
              }
            });
          } 
        } 
        });
        
        this.service.getLatestLogBookID(false).subscribe({
          next: (response) => {
            if (response['value'][0] != undefined) {
              let maxVaule = response['value'][0].id;
              this.service.getLatestLogBookID(true).subscribe({
                next: (result) => {
                  const spConfigValue: number = 4999; //+environment.documentsGridLimit;                
                  let lobvalue = (+maxVaule / spConfigValue);
                  if (!Number.isInteger(lobvalue)) {
                    lobvalue = Math.floor(lobvalue) + 1;
                  }
                  let array = [];
                  let initailValue = +result['value'][0].id;
                  let endValue = initailValue + spConfigValue;
                  for (let f = 0; f < lobvalue; f++) {
                    let filter = initailValue + ',' + endValue;
                    array.push(filter);
                    initailValue = endValue + 1;
                    endValue = endValue + spConfigValue;
                  }
                  combineLatest(array.map(number => this.service.getLogBookGrid(number, spConfigValue.toString()))).subscribe((res: any) => {
                    res.map(item => {
                      console.log('forkJoin - ' + this.modelList.length + ' - ' + item?.['value'].length);
                      this.modelList1.push(item);
                      let dd = --array.length;
                      if (dd == 0) {
                      const response = {
                        spListMaxId: maxVaule,
                        spListMinId: result['value'][0].id,
                        model: this.modelList1
                      }
                      observer.next(response);
                      observer.complete();
                      console.log(this.modelList1,"array")
                    }
                    });
                  });
                }
              });
            }          } 
          });
   });
  } 
}
```

Comment: Little tip if you want to increase your chances of having people taking the time to help you out. Create a **minimal** repro on stackblitz. Don't just dump your entire code. If you don't take the time to create a minimal repro once on your side, you shift that mental burden to all people who are going to read your post and try to help you out. Except that a lot of people will drop out, as you've made no efforts initially. Isolate the issue, make a repro as tiny as possible, and I'm pretty sure you'll get some help from the community

Answer (score 1):

the main problem is that you should never subscribe inside an observable.
If you follow this rule creating a new observable like this `return new Observable(observer => {` won't be necessary anymore.

You should concatenate your observable using concatMap or switchMap.

a short example would be:

```
doYourStuff$(): Observable<any> {

  return this.service.getCOALatestLogBookID(false).pipe(
    concatMap(latestLogBookID -> {
      console.log("latestLogBookID false", latestLogBookID);
      // some code
      return this.service.getCOALatestLogBookID(true);
    }),
    concatMap(latestLogBookID -> {
      console.log("latestLogBookID true", latestLogBookID);
      // some code
      return this.service.getCOALogBookGrid(yourVariables).pipe(
         map(bookGrid -> {
           console.log("bookGrig", bookGrid);
           // do some stuff
           return "whatever you want to return";
         })
      );
    }),
  );

}
```

of course the code above won't work but it's to illustrate you with an example how you can concatenate your request.

The key is to never subscribe but always return an observable.

what you can also do is to declare a variable for each observable and return that variable i.e.

```
// some code
concatMap(latestLogBookID -> {
    // some code
    const myObservable1$ = this.service.getCOALogBookGrid(yourVariables).pipe(
     map(bookGrid -> {
       console.log("bookGrig", bookGrid);
       // do some stuff
       return "whatever you want to return";
     })
    );
    return myObservable1$;
}
// some code
```

the result will be exactly the same but it's a little simple to debug because you can hover over `myObservable1$` with your mouse and see what it actually returns.